# Выравнивание текста в TextEdit

Tags: c++, qt5

Делаю обычный текстовый редактор на Qt 5.11. Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу найти как реализовать позиционирование текста по левому/правому краю и по центру (как в word-е и в любом другом текстовом редакторе). Нужна помощь в реализации трех этих слотов. Текст помещен в TextEdit

Answer (score 0):

У вас два варианта: используя `QTextCursor`/`QTextBlockFormat`:

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
QTextBlockFormat format;
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfBlock);   cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::EndOfBlock, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor); // Выделяем первую строку
format = cursor.blockFormat();
format.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
cursor.setBlockFormat(format);
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextBlock,QTextCursor::MoveAnchor,1); // двигаем курсор
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfBlock); cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::EndOfBlock, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor); //выделяем следующую строку
format = cursor.blockFormat();
format.setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
cursor.setBlockFormat(format);
```

Или при добавлении форматировать в html:

```
ui->textEdit->document()->setHtml("<p>left</p> <p align=\"center\">center</p> <p align=\"right\">right</p>");
```